# Change Google Sheet tab name using Script and GID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

Using google App script I try to change google sheet tab names. However as the tabs change names regularly the idea is uisng the GID instead in the script to change the ID. Imagine table below: having a table with a column of the supposed sheet name and then the gid of the tab that should have that name.

| Name Event | GID |
| --- | --- |
| abc jan 12 | 981289394 |
| BCD jan 18 | 901985265 |
| ZYX feb 18 | 1085929622 |

Is this possible and how would this look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the sheet name can be changed using "GID" (sheet ID) using Google Apps Script. In your table, when "Name Event" and "GID" are the columns "A" and "B", respectively, and this table is the same with the Spreadsheet including the sheets you want to rename, how about the following script?

The flow of this script is as follows.

1. Retrieve the table for renaming the sheet name using GID from the sheet.
2. Create an object for searching the GID.
3. Rename the sheet name using GIDs retrieved from the source sheet.

In this sample script, in your table, 1st column and 2nd column are retrieved, and the values of 2nd column are used as the GID list. And, the values of 1st column are used as the sheet name you want to rename.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the Spreadsheet and please set the sheet name which includes the table in your question. When you use this script, please run `myFunction`. By this, the values are retrieved from the source sheet, and the sheets are renamed using the retrieved values of `Name Event` and `GID`.

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name of the sheet of your table in your question. This is a source sheet.

  // 1. Retrieve the table for renaming the sheet name using GID from the sheet.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const data = srcSheet.getRange("A2:B" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // 2. Create an object for searching the GID.
  const sheetObj = ss.getSheets().reduce((o, sheet) => Object.assign(o, {[sheet.getSheetId()]: sheet}), {});

  // 3. Rename the sheet name using GIDs retrieved from the source sheet.
  data.forEach(([name, gid]) => {
    if (sheetObj[gid] && !ss.getSheetByName(name)) {
      sheetObj[gid].setName(name);
    }
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, it supposes that "Name Event" and "GID" are the columns "A" and "B", respectively, and the sheets, which have the GIDs, are the same Spreadsheet with the source sheet. Please be careful this. If this was the difference from your actual situation, please tell me.
- At Google Spreadsheet, the same sheet names cannot be created in a Google Spreadsheet. So please be careful this.

#### References:

- [getSheetId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getsheetid)
- [setName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setnamename)

Comment: Brilliant! i was unfamiliar especially with the step 2 and 3. works like a charm!

Comment: @Christiaan Lennaerts Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About 2nd part, in this case, a JSON object is created, and this is used for searching GID. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) About 3rd part, each value is retrieved from the data retrieved from the source sheet in the loop, and the GID value is searched using the JSON object, and when the GID value is existing in the source sheet, the sheet name is changed. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.